# MySQL group by loop bash

Tags: mysql, bash, loops

I'm having trouble using MySQL; it pull extra data.
I have a data base with IPs and Host in it:

```
ips         host
127.0.0.1  host1.exampl.com
127.0.0.2  host2.exampl.com
127.0.0.3  host3.exampl.com
127.0.0.4  host4.exampl.com
127.0.0.5  host5.exampl.com
```

Next, I have a file `ips.txt`:

```
127.0.0.2
127.0.0.4
```

And I have a bash script:

```
for i in `cat ips.txt` ; do echo "ip, host from ip_group_list where ip like '%$i%' GROUP BY ip" | mysql -uroot -p$PSSWD  database -N  >> ipsandhost.txt; done
```

I want it to return

```
127.0.0.2  host2.exampl.com
127.0.0.4  host4.exampl.com
```

However it returns

```
127.0.0.1  host1.exampl.com
127.0.0.2  host2.exampl.com
127.0.0.3  host3.exampl.com
127.0.0.4  host4.exampl.com
127.0.0.5  host5.exampl.com
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: You're missing `SELECT` at the beginning of the query. How is it returning anything at all?

Comment: There's no column `ip` in your table, it's called `ips`. After I fixed these two errors, I tried your script and it worked as you wanted for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need neither %% nor GROUP BY

```
for i in `cat ips.txt` ; do 
  echo "SELECT ip, host from ip_group_list where ip = '$i'" | mysql -uroot -p$PSSWD  database -N  >> ipsandhost.txt; 
done
```

Comment: If you don't have `%` you should use `=` instead of `like`

Comment: Yes, you're right. At least from the example is clear %% are  not necessary

Comment: But it should also have worked the way he wrote it. How does this address the problem?

Comment: I don't really think it worked. Without SELECT, but with GROUP BY :)